# Disable Keyboard from TimePicker in Xamarin Form ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, timepicker

[image: Keyboard shows when user clicks on AM/PM]

How to disable the keyboard from showing up when the user taps on a time ?

I am using a simple TimePicker in xamarin forms for ios app

Comment: What is your xaml , because when i make a new project in Xamarin Forms and a normal TimePicker and run it on real iOS device the Keyboard is not showing.

Comment: From your Comment on the Answer <controls:CustomTimePicker Keyboard = "None"/>  This is not a normal TimePicker

Comment: @BasH  <controls:CustomTimePicker HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="300"  FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold"  Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.Column="1" Time="{Binding CurrentTimeStamp, Mode=TwoWay}" />.    its a customTimePicker ..in renderer i am just setting Text Alighnment to center

Comment: With Custom controle's there usally a Class with the CustomPicker , can you put a small working example on Github . Or a link where you found the CustomPicker .

Comment: I created a project using customTimePicker according to what you said, using the same layout as you in Xaml, and just set the Text Alignment to center in the renderer, tested the project and the keyboard did not appear. Can you provide more of your code about customTimePicker?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT click on the digits appearing in the Time Picker.. its happening in ios 16 onwards

Comment: @MainakChoudhury I am using the iPhone 13 Pro Max simulator for testing. I have tested iOS15.4, iOS16.0 and iOS16.2 and none of the three versions reproduced your problem. Can you provide some detailed code?

Answer (score -1):

To disable the keyboard from showing up when the user taps on a time in a Xamarin.Forms iOS app, you can set the Keyboard property of the TimePicker control to None.

```
<TimePicker Keyboard="None" />
```

This will prevent the keyboard from appearing when the user taps on the TimePicker control, and they will be able to select a time using the built-in time picker UI.

Comment: <controls:CustomTimePicker Keyboard = "None"/> ....xamarin/VS is not recognizing the "Keyboard" tag